# Compilation warning for Objects that contain non Copyable objects are unreadable

Tags: c++, compilation, copy-constructor, static-assert

I've asked a similiar question before but now I'd like to be more specific.
The problem I face is that I have an object that contains a non copyable object and when someone wants to use my interface and he does not use it well (does try to use the object's copy constructor) he will get a compilation error that will point to the object and not his actual code.
So two questions:
1. can I fix it somehow to point it to his original code line?
2. if I cannot, how can I put a static_assert that will only happen if someone actually tries to use the copy c'tor(I've tried a few but then I get them even if someone doesn't use it...)

I am adding a sample code and the compilation error in case I was not understood...
Notice the last compile error points to the ObjectHolder h. file.. while I want it to point to the main
Thanks!

*** was a mistake when I replaced names.. it is in fact the code that created the compilation error.
and Let's assume I don't want to implement a private copy c'tor just to forward the disability to copy

```
class NonCopyableObject 
{
    public:
        virtual ~NonCopyableObject () {}

        NonCopyableObject(int i) { m_index = i;}
        int m_index;
    private:
        NonCopyableObject(const NonCopyableObject& other) {}
};

class ObjectHolder 
{
    public:
        virtual ~ObjectHolder ();
        ObjectHolder(int i) : obj(i) {}

        NonCopyableObject obj;
};

void main()
{
    ObjectHolder first(1);
    ObjectHolder second(first);
}

1>------ Build started: Project: tester, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>d:\users\someone\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\tester\tester\objectholder.h(13): error C2248: 'NonCopyableObject::NonCopyableObject' : cannot access private member declared in class 'NonCopyableObject'
1>          d:\users\someone\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\tester\tester\noncopyableobject.h(15) : see declaration of 'NonCopyableObject::NonCopyableObject'
1>          d:\users\someone\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\tester\tester\noncopyableobject.h(8) : see declaration of 'NonCopyableObject'
1>          This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'ObjectHolder::ObjectHolder(const ObjectHolder &)'
```

Comment: Try to hide the copy constructor in ObjectHolder too

Comment: I'm sure this is NOT the actual code which resulted in the compilation error posted here.

Comment: If you don't want your object to have an accessible copy constructor, make it `private` (or, in C++11, `delete` it).

Comment: Why would you want that? The compiler diagnostics on all major compilers tell you that you're trying to use a private constructor. Simply document the fact that your class is not copyable in your API doc. If one of your users then tries to copy it, runs into this error, and cannot figure out what's going on, they don't know enough about C++ and *you cannot fix that*.

Comment: I have editted it so it is the same code.. sorry for the copy replacve error, and indeed they are novices in c++, but if they want to find out they're error they'll have to comment they're entire code just in order to find out...

Answer (score 1):

The error messages supplied do not reflect the code supplied.

That aside you have an error. Considering the code:

```
class ObjectHolder 
{
    public:
        virtual ~ObjectHolder ();
        ObjectHolder(int i) : obj(i) {}

        ObjectHolder obj;
};
```

How is the compiler suppose to ascertain the amount of memory required for an `ObjectHolder` when it is recursive?

Comment: Was a mistake when I copied it !!.. it is actually 
class ObjectHolder 
{
    public:
        virtual ~ObjectHolder ();
        ObjectHolder(int i) : obj(i) {}

        NonCopyableObject obj;
};